# android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter cannot be applied to android.app.FragmentManager

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-tabs, fragmentpageradapter

I want to implement just 2 fixed tabs in my application.
I followed this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/).

In my `TabPagerAdapter` class I'm getting this error :

`FragmentPageAdapter` in `android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter` cannot be applied to `android.app.FragmentManager`

**TabPageAdapter class:**

```
package com.nikhil.tabs;


import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;


public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm); //getting error here
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) { //getting error here

        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                // Top Rated fragment activity
                return new TopRatedFragment();
            case 1:
                // Games fragment activity
                return new GamesFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 2;
    }

}
```

**Why is that error caused and how to solve it?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Error occurs because your `FragmentPagerAdapter` uses **support libraries** and `Fragment` and `FragmentManager` **don't**!

Change

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
```

To

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

Comment: Thanks! Clear as a crystal. I missed it. :)

Comment: Thanks really Helpful :)